# How to add relation to "static" table in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-relations

First off all I'm using SQL Server CE and I've created a data context for my database to handle it in C# code.

This is my problem:

In `TableA`, there are several "static" items that won't change: they are "attributes" like the following:

```
Name=available 24 hours, ID=1, isset=1
```

where `Name` is a string, `ID` type of int and `isset` a bit.

There are about 100 attributes in the list.

Now, I have `TableB` with items that can have these attributes. I can't add a relation between a Column `AttributeID` and the `attributeID`, because the item can have several.

But I can't add a column with the `itemID` in the `attributes` table either, because several items can have this attribute.

So what can I do? Is there a way in SQL Server CE to achieve this?

EDIT: So, I'll try to explain more clearly:

My `TableA` is a table with 3 columns: `Name`, `ID` and `isset`.
Each row in this `TableA` represents one item, let's call it `itemA`.
There are about 100 rows (= 100 `itemA`) in the table.

Now, my `TableB` represents `itemB` that can have one or several of these `itemA`.

But I don't know how to do this: It wouldn't work to add a relation between a column of `TableB` called `itemA_ID` and the column of `TableA` called `ID`, because one `itemB` can contain more than one `itemA`. But the opposite way round, it wouldn't work either: A relation between a column `itemB_ID` of `TableA` and a column of `TableB` called `ID` is neither possible, because one `itemA` can refer to more than one `itemB`.

I know it's a bit complicated but I hope that it's a bit easier to understand now.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you give us more than a single example of what you mean? Also, avoid vague terms like "Name", "Attribute", "Item", and so on. Use names of the actual data you will be storing.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is a RDBMS, and if no RDBMS features fit the bill, then no - maybe you are modelling your data in a wrong way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, but I am guessing you have a one-to-many relation. That is, you have many "Item"s, each of which can have many "attributes".

The way to handle this is to create a lookup table for each relation. E.g.:

```
TableA
AttributeID  Availability
          1  Available 24 hours
          2  Available 48 hours

TableB
ItemID  IsSet  ItemName
     1      1  Something

TableC
ItemID  AttributeID
     1            1
     1            2
```

If that is not what you mean, please provide examples of your data.